# Mixing two lists of items so that the result looks natural and not artificial

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have two lists of items in different categories, lets say A & B, there are m A's and n B's. I want to mix the two lists into a single list so the result keeps the order of A and the order of B but combines them in a way which doesn't look artificial.

If m and n where similar a stupid version would be to alternate A B A B but that looks unnatural. Something like A A B A B A B B A A etc looks less fake. In most cases there are more A's than B's but it's not guaranteed. Generally there are 125 A and 50 B and never more but can be filtered down to as little as 1.

I've built one which is based on the ratio of m/n but of course it highly regular. I tried to add a bit of random element into it but still doesn't look quite right.

The right look is clearly subjective, obviously if there was a solid statistical foundation the code would be easier to write. Any ideas are welcome. Even telling me the correct search terms in google would help if there is a branch of math or statistics that does stuff like this.

Writing this in Objective-C but I don't need code, just algorithm or ideas.

UPDATE: I investigated various things suggested but some were too complicated, especially things like Sobol sequences). What I am doing at the moment is using the random algorithm (add the total A and B together, pick random int from 0 to total-1, if less the total A pick A) but I added a check to ensure that no more than 2 B's show up consecutively (since B count is virtually always less than half the As). Not perfect yet but it does look a bit less random. You do wind up with an excess of B's stuck to the end, but these are less desirable from a business point anyway. Sobol et all would ensure better mixing but it's way too much effort for this.

Comment: Idea: `man 3 arc4random`

Comment: Add the length of A and B together.  Generate a random number between 0 and length - 1.  Pick the next value of either A or B based on the random number (less than A length, A; otherwise B).  Repeat until the output is as long as you want.

Comment: that's what I am using atm - arc4random

Comment: about to try that one

Comment: I think what you actually want is call a [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Append the two lists together then shuffle.

Comment: Is there way to limit a shuffle so you can control the max length of runs? So you could avoid A A A A A B B B B A B kind of clumping?

Comment: @ahwulf I don't have a concrete idea yet. but the keyword you might want to look for is [low-discrepancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence). Somehow... use those [low-discrepancy sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence) in doing the shuffle?

Comment: interesting, will check that out

Comment: @Billiska: I don't think he wants a shuffle. He wants the order of A's to be the same and the order of B's to be the same. He just wants to interleave A's and B's. A shuffle would randomize the order of elements.

Comment: @JimMischel certainly, the OP isn't clear about whether he wants to preserve the order *within* A and B or not. Can only let him modify the question.

Comment: @Billska: It's hard to misinterpret the OP's second sentence: "I want to mix the two lists into a single list so the result *keeps the order of A and the order of B* but combines them in a way which doesn't look artificial."

Comment: Yes the original A and B order amongst themselves should be preserved.

Comment: Adrian McCarthy's solution is the mathematically correct one, you shouldn't be bounding the number of consecutive B's because in reality runs of values occur.  That's how we know Mendel's lab assistant fudged the numbers, there was less variation in the counts than there should have been.  McCarthy's suggestion dynamically corrects - each time you pick an A the next choice is a little more likely to be a B and vice versa, but in the right proportions.

Comment: @JimMischel Completely missed that. sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given *m* A's and *n* B's:

```
while (m + n > 0) {
  float r = a random number in the range 0..1;
  if (r < m / (m + n)) {  // use floating point arithmetic
    choose the next A;
    --m;
  } else {
    choose the next B;
    --n;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a way of generating a random integer in the range `[0,m+n)` you could eliminate the floating-point requirement and use `r < m`.

Comment: As OP said in the comment, he is worried about discrepancy of output which is likely to occur in this algorithm. One such situation is when `len(A) << len(B)`. The output of this post will have the **bias** that A is likely to appear only at the beginning of the output.

Comment: @Billiska: If there is 1 'A' and 99 'B', the likelihood of A being at the beginning of the sequence is no higher than the likelihood of it being at the end.

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you for the correction. Yes, the chance is exactly the same as random shuffle. The point I should have made is rather the OP want to "avoid A A A A A B B B B A B kind of clumping". That is he actually want to bias it towards low discrepancy output.

Comment: Yes that's why I looked at Sobol et al. In the end it was rather easy to do the random thing with a run avoider.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to sample uniformly at random from the words with the right letter counts that are accepted by a specified deterministic automaton. The algorithm is a dynamic program over the states of the automaton and the numbers of symbols remaining. Here's some sample outputs with 20 a's and 20 b's:

```
abbaabbbaabbbabaaabbaaababbaaabbbabbbaaa
bbaaababababbaaabbababababbbabaaababaabb
bbababbbaaabaaabbbabaabaaabbbaababbababa
ababbbabbababbbaabababbaababaabbaaababaa
bbaaababbababbabaabbababaabababaabababba
bbaabbababbbaabbababaaabaababbbaababaaab
babaabaabbababbababbababbaababaaababbaba
aaabababaababbabbababbbaabbababaabbaaabb
babababbabaaababababababaababbbaabbaabba
bbabaabababababbabaababaababbbaabbabaaba
```

Here's the Python that produced these.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import product, repeat
from random import random


"""
deterministic finite automata
delta is a dict from state-symbol pairs to states
q0 is the initial state
F is the set of accepting states
"""
DFA = namedtuple('DFA', ('delta', 'q0', 'F'))


"""accepts strings with no runs of length 4"""
noruns4 = DFA(
    delta={
        ('0', 'a'): '1a',
        ('0', 'b'): '1b',
        ('1a', 'a'): '2a',
        ('1a', 'b'): '1b',
        ('1b', 'a'): '1a',
        ('1b', 'b'): '2b',
        ('2a', 'a'): '3a',
        ('2a', 'b'): '1b',
        ('2b', 'a'): '1a',
        ('2b', 'b'): '3b',
        ('3a', 'a'): '4',
        ('3a', 'b'): '1b',
        ('3b', 'a'): '1a',
        ('3b', 'b'): '4',
        ('4', 'a'): '4',
        ('4', 'b'): '4'},
    q0='0',
    F={'0', '1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b'})


def accepts(dfa, s):
    """returns whether dfa accepts s"""
    q = dfa.q0
    for c in s:
        q = dfa.delta[(q, c)]
    return q in dfa.F


def testaccepts():
    for n in range(10):
        for cs in product(*repeat('ab', n)):
            s = ''.join(cs)
            if not accepts(noruns4, s) != ('aaaa' in s or 'bbbb' in s):
                print(s)
                assert False


testaccepts()


def acceptedstrcnts(dfa, syms, cnts, memo=None, q=None):
    """
    counts the number of strings accepted by dfa,
    subject to the constraint of having the specified number of symbols
    """
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    if q is None:
        q = dfa.q0
    key = (q,) + tuple(cnts)
    if key not in memo:
        if sum(cnts) > 0:
            total = 0
            for (i, cnt) in enumerate(cnts):
                if cnt > 0:
                    newcnts = list(cnts)
                    newcnts[i] -= 1
                    newq = dfa.delta[(q, syms[i])]
                    total += acceptedstrcnts(dfa, syms, newcnts, memo, newq)
        else:
            total = 1.0 if q in dfa.F else 0.0
        memo[key] = total
    return memo[key]


print(acceptedstrcnts(noruns4, 'ab', (125, 50)))
memo = {}
acceptedstrcnts(noruns4, 'ab', (4, 4), memo)
# 62 strings with 4 a's, 4 b's, and no runs
print(memo)


def memoget(memo, q, cnts):
    return memo[(q,) + tuple(cnts)]


def samplestrcnts(dfa, syms, cnts, memo):
    """
    uses the memoization dict to sample the counted words
    modulo roundoff error, the sampling is uniform
    """
    cnts = list(cnts)
    cs = []
    q = dfa.q0
    while sum(cnts) > 0:
        denom = memoget(memo, q, cnts)
        outcome = random()
        j = None
        for (i, cnt) in enumerate(cnts):
            if cnt > 0:
                j = i  # default in case roundoff bites us
                newcnts = list(cnts)
                newcnts[i] -= 1
                newq = dfa.delta[(q, syms[i])]
                numer = memoget(memo, newq, newcnts)
                ratio = numer / denom
                if outcome < ratio:
                    break
                outcome -= ratio
        cnts[j] -= 1
        cs.append(syms[j])
        q = dfa.delta[(q, syms[j])]
    return ''.join(cs)


acceptedstrcnts(noruns4, 'ab', (20, 20), memo)
for k in range(10):
    print(samplestrcnts(noruns4, 'ab', (20, 20), memo))
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but probably too much work. I also wonder about how long this would take with 175 total items.

Comment: @ahwulf For this crappy implementation, <2ms. I would expect a two-orders-of-magnitude improvement in Objective-C with less generic data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach based on Metropolis–Hastings.

```
from math import log2
from random import randrange


def simscore(lst, j):
    score = 0
    if j > 0 and lst[j] == lst[j - 1]:
        score += 1
    if j < len(lst) - 1 and lst[j] == lst[j + 1]:
        score += 1
    return score


def mix(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(len(lst) * (100 + round(log2(n + 1)))):
        j = randrange(n)
        k = randrange(n)
        oldscore = simscore(lst, j) + simscore(lst, k)
        (lst[j], lst[k]) = (lst[k], lst[j])
        newscore = simscore(lst, j) + simscore(lst, k)
        if not (newscore <= oldscore or randrange(4 ** (newscore - oldscore)) == 0):
            (lst[j], lst[k]) = (lst[k], lst[j])


lst = list(125 * 'a' + 50 * 'b')
for i in range(10):
    mix(lst)
    print(''.join(lst))
```

Here are some samples:

```
ababababaaababaabaabbabaabaaaaabaaabaababaaaabababaabaababaaabaaabaaabaabaababaaaababaaabaaaaaaabaaabaaaaaaaaabaabaabaaaababaaaaaababababaaabaabaabaaababaabaabaaabaaaaaaaabaaa
aaaaaaabababaaaaabaaabaaabaabaaaaaababaaaabaaaabaaaaaabaaabababaaabaaaaaaabbaababaabaabababaabababaababaaabaababaaaaabaabaaaaaaaabaabaaaababaabaaaaaababaaabababbababababaabaaa
ababababaabaaabbababaaababbaaaabaabaaaabaabaaaababaabababaaababaaaabaaabaaaaaaabaaaabaaababaaaaaaaababaaaabaaababaaaaabaaaabaaaababaabaababaaabaaaaababaababaaaaabaabaabaabaaaa
aaaaaababababaaaaaabaaaabaabaaabababaaabaaaabaaababaabaaaaaaaababaababaaaaabaaabaababaaaaabaaaabababaaaababaabababababbaaabaaaaabbaaaaaabababbaaabaabaaabaaaaaabbaaaaaabaaababa
ababaababaaababababaabaaaaaaabaababaabaaaaaaaaabaabaabaababaabaababababaabaabababababaaabaabababaaaaaaabaabaaaabababaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaababaaaaabbaaababaaabaaaaaaababaab
baababaabaabaaabababaaaabaabaababaaaababaabaaaaaabababaabaaaaaaaababaaaaabababaaaabaabababababababaaaaaababaaaabaaaaaaabaaabaaabaaaabaabaaaaaababaaaaaaababaababaabababaaaaaaab
aabaabaaaabababaabaababaaaaabaaaaabaabaaaaababaaababaaababaaaaababaaabaaabaaaabaabababababaaaabaabbabaabaabaabaababaabaabaaaabaaababaaabaabaaaaaabababaaaaaaaabaaaaaaabaaabaaab
babaaaaaababbaaaabababaaaaabaaabababbaaaabaabaaababaabababaabaaabaababaaababaaabaaabaabaababaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaababaabaaabaabaababaaabababbaaaaaabaaaaaaabaaaaaaaabaaaaababaabaaba
aabaaabaaaaaabaababaabaaaaaaaaaaaabababaaababaababaababaaabaabaaabaabaabaaaaabaabaaaabaaabaabaabaababaabaabaabaaaaaaabaabbabaaaabaabaabaaaaaabaaababaaaabaaabaaabbababaabaababa
baaaabababaaaabaaababaabaaaababaaaaabaaaaaaabaaabababbaabababaaaabaabaaaaaabaaaabababababbaaabaaaaabaaaaaabaabaaabaaaaaaaaabaababbaabababaaaabaabaabaababaabababaaaaaaabaaabaaa
```